# Multiple visible views responding to one gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller that consists of three views (self.panedview, self.view, self.sineview)  When a swipe up gesture is detected, the highest view (self.panedview) is moved up halfway - revealing two additional views (self.view and self.sineview).  self.sineview is a UIView that constantly has an animation running that renders a moving sinewave and takes up half of self.view.  I have a swipe down gesture recognizer that works when I swipe down on self.panedview, but doesn't work when I swipe down on self.sineview.  If I swipe around self.sineview on self.view it seems to work.  When I hide self.sineview and swipe directly down on either self.view or self.paned view, the swipe down works.  do you think the animating sine wave gets in the way of the gesture recognition.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeDownRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDownSwipe:)];
[self.panedView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRec];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRec]; 
[self.sineview addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRec];
```

Also I tried varying between these two lines of code but there is no difference:

```
    [self.view insertSubview:self.sineWave belowSubview:self.panedView];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.sineWave aboveSubview:self.view];
```

I also tried adding a separate swipe down gesture recognizer for each view, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest using seperate `UISwipeGestureRecognizers`, that way you can explicitly do what you need to based on which recognizer was recognized in one method.

Comment: I made a separate `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` for each view but they all had the same selector method for action, but it still doesn't work.  Like I mentioned, when I hide the `self.sineview`, both `self.panedview` and `self.view` respond to one `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` perfectly.  I'm suspicious the animation is getting in the way

Comment: Did you declare properties for each recognizer? and determine which one is being recognized in the method?

Comment: Which properties are you referring to?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this sooner, but I disabled the animation that makes the sine wave look like its moving and the swipe worked.  I think its safe to assume that the gesture recognizer is unable to recognize a swipe directly over self.sineview when the animation is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the that the swipe recognizer for self.sinewave couldn't be recognized while the self.sinewave animation was enabled.  The solution is simple: add `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` as a parameter to the `options` handler for `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`